# Plotting emmean results with grouped colours in R

Tags: r, plot, colors, grouping, emmeans

I am trying to plot my emmean results from `emm<- emmeans(m1, ~ Shape*Item)`, and the best I’ve come up with so far is when using `plot(emm, col = "purple") + theme_classic() + ylab("Shape : Item")`

I’ve tried many many things (with emm and emm as a dataframe), but I cant figure out how to have different colours per shape (one colour for triangle planned performance and another for spear planned performance).
[image: emm plot]

emm contains:
Shape = c('SPP', 'TPP', 'SPP', 'TPP', 'SPP', 'TPP', 'SPP', 'TPP', 'SPP', 'TPP', 'SPP', 'TPP', 'SPP', 'TPP'),
Item = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7),
emmean = c(4.86, 5.02, 5.85, 5.81, 4.68, 5.28, 5.21, 5.50, 3.95, 4.30, 5.02, 4.93, 4.84, 5.04),
SE = c(0.112, 0.113, 0.113, 0.112, 0.112, 0.113, 0.112, 0.113, 0.113, 0.112, 0.113, 0.112, 0.113, 0.112),
df = c(105, 106, 106, 105, 105, 106, 104, 107, 106, 105, 107, 104, 106, 105),
lower.CL = c(4.64, 4.80, 5.62, 5.59, 4.46, 5.05, 4.98, 5.27, 3.72, 4.07, 4.80, 4.71, 4.61, 4.81),
upper.CL = c(5.08, 5.24, 6.07, 6.03, 4.90, 5.50, 5.43, 5.72, 4.17, 4.52, 5.24, 5.16, 5.06, 5.26)

Comment: Please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

Comment: Although I'd still like to know the answer, I've decided to just use ggplot instead, using
ggplot(df, aes(x = emmean, y = Item, color = Shape)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.4), alpha = 0.7) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = lower.CL, xmax = upper.CL), position = position_dodge(width = 0.4), height = 0.1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("orange", "blue")) +
  labs(x = "Estimated Marginal Means", y = "Shape") +
  theme_classic()